# addOBject returning NULL?

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to code and I don't understand why this works fine when I type it on a main file and start a command line project:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray *myArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int anID = 0; anID < (20); anID++)
        {
            [myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:anID]];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", myArray);     
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and returns as expected an array populated with numbers:

```
2015-10-21 21:10:01.783 quicktry[3268:727372] (
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17,
    18,
    19
)
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

But the exact same thing doesn't work if I do it as a class:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *myArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];


    for (int anID = 0; anID < (20); anID++)
    {
        [self.myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:anID]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", self.myArray);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This returns NULL. As far as I can tell, it's exactly the same code. Why doesn't this work here?

Comment: when I say returns I mean logs out to the console.

Comment: You did not initialize `self.myArray`. Calling any method on nil is a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting init your property.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

// You forget this:
self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  for (int anID = 0; anID < (20); anID++) { [self.myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:anID]];

} NSLog(@"%@", self.myArray);

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I thought declaring a property automatically did the alloc init. Would make sense right? early days...

Comment: No in objective -C. A property is only a pointer. You can declare a property as id (any object).

Comment: @Dave If you want, you can override the accessors so that a new instance will be created and set for you if you try to access the property while it's nil.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've forgotten to actually create the array. I see the property declaration, but nowhere is the property set to an empty array before you access it.

In Objective-C *sending a message to nil returns nil*, thus why you can send "addObject:" to a nil property and log the result still.